# Why is std::basic_string<char> segfaulting on my overloaded stream operator?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, cygwin

I'm trying to compile and run this harmless looking class in g++ but the program keeps segfaulting either on malloc or memmove. There is hardly anything going on here.

I receive the following error when compiling with -g and running it through gdb. This is the extent of what I know on how to debug this.

**For some reason this only segfaults when compiled from two separate files. If I copy/paste everything into main.cpp it runs fine.**

Windows/Cygwin g++ (GCC) 4.9.2:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> 0x61137eb5 in memmove () from /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll

..

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> 0x610ef417 in muto::acquire(unsigned long) () from /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll

Windows/g++ 4.9.2-TDM:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> 0x777d27d0 in ntdll!RtlCompareMemoryUlong () from /c/Windows/SysWOW64/ntdll.dll
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00007ffff7279ef5 in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
>   Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-55.el7_0.5.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.2-16.2.el7_0.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.2-16.2.el7_0.x86_64
>   ..

CentOS 7/g++ (GCC) 4.8.2:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> _int_malloc (av=0x7ffff75b6760 , bytes=29) at malloc.c:3281
>
> 3281    {

I'm compiling using the following flags:

```
-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wnoexcept -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-promo -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Wno-unused
```

What am I missing? Is there anything else I can do in gdb to help pinpoint the problem?

```
$ g++ main.cpp string_t.cpp -g -std=c++11 $DEBUG -o test.exe && ./test.exe
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include "string_t.h"

int main() {
   string_t a("test");

   cout << a << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

string_t.h

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

class string_t {
std::basic_string<char> _base;

public:
   string_t(
      const char* s);

   friend std::ostream& operator<<(
      std::ostream& l,
      const string_t& r);
};
```

string_t.cpp

```
#include "string_t.h"

string_t::string_t(
   const char* s) :
   _base(s) {
}

std::ostream& operator<<(
   std::ostream& l,
   const string_t& r)
{
   l << r._base.c_str();

   return l;
}
```

Comment: Your code compiles fine with g++ for me (after adding the missing `#include <cstdint>`).

Comment: The standard doesn't mandate that implementations provide a specialization of `char_traits` for `unsigned char` (which is almost certainly what `uint8_t` is typedefed as). I'm surprised that it segfaults, it runs fine on my own mingw + gcc trunk build, but technically you're in no man's land and you should probably change your design instead of wasting time trying to figure out where it's going wrong.

Comment: Changed all of the uint8_t to chars and it still segfauls but in a different place. A good guess though.

Comment: You're still missing a `#include <iostream>` include in `string_t.h`.

Comment: Can you include the backtrace when you get the segmentation fault?

Comment: How do I get a backtrace?

Comment: I can confirm that this segfault SHOULD be duplicable. It happens on my Windows box under Cygwin, native with TDM (MINGW), as well as a completely separate machine running CentOS 7. The key here is to make sure that you compile with the two .cpp files-- don't try to combine them into main.cpp.

Comment: @Zhro Yes well, if you'd actually posted the exact code that was causing the issue in the first place you would have had your answer much sooner. The point about `char_traits` still stands, this isn't portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not include `<ostream>` into the second translation unit (string_t.cpp), so overload resolution fails to find

```
template<class CharT, class Traits>
basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator << (basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os, const char* s);
```

when you invoke

```
l << r._base.c_str();
```

Instead, `string_t(const char* s)` is used as a conversion constructor (it is not declared `explicit`) to create a new string_t object and

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& l, const string_t& r)
```

is called again, so you end up with infinite recursion.

Comment: Yes, this fixes it! I'm still unclear as to what was going on though. How did string_t.cpp even compile without std::ostream being in scope?

Comment: I would also like to hear what kind of defensive strategies could have prevented this error and, in the face of a large code base, how can this be tracked down? This wouldn't be the first time I've shot myself in the foot but this one was extremely deceptive.

Comment: Unfortunately std::ostream was in scope (<string> includes <iosfwd>, which contains forward declaration of ostream - otherwise it would be impossible to define << operator for string).

Comment: The defensive strategy is, perhaps, to declare constructors with one argument as explicit (unless you know that you need implicit conversions).
I tracked the problem down by looking at GCC's intermediate representation (see -fdump-tree-gimple option) - but that's somewhat "hardcore", perhaps you could just use GDB to figure out what happens.